# Measure Performance per layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, performance, rendering, memory

I'm working in a relatively large project in QGIS 2.14, mostly loaded with .shp files. The issue is that lately got painfully slow when zooming or changing map view. I've tried to delete the largest layers and performed spatial indexing for all layers with no luck.

Is there a way to identify which layer is using more resources and slowing down the project?

Comment: On-the-fly projections may be an issue. Do each of your layer's CRS match the project's CRS?

Comment: Actually they do not match.. Is there a way to batch convert them all?

Comment: Got it.. i will try http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131508/qgis-batch-shp-transform and post back. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a useful debugging tool, from memory it came in QGIS 2.18

Go to settings and under 'Rendering', look for 'Debugging' (you may need to scroll down to see it) and check the box.

[image]

Now, the **rendering** tab on the **Log messages panel** shows per-layer rendering times.

[image]